# hwclock for non root user

Tags: non-root-user, clock

How to make a non root user to view the hardware time other than `hwclock` command in centos 7

My requirement is to make a non root user to view the time alone

Answer (score 4):

One could setup a [sudo rule](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-security-cookbook/0596003919/ch05s09.html) to allow the execution of `hwclock` without any arguments:

`%sudo     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/hwclock ""`

Or grant *read* access to the [RTC](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt) character device:

```
$ groups 
johnny sudo staff

$ sudo setfacl -m g:sudo:r /dev/rtc
$ /sbin/hwclock
Sun 18 Dec 2016 03:16:37 PM PST  -0.318689 seconds
```

This may have to be set after every reboot, as `/dev` is most likely volatile these days. I suppose an `udev` rule could handle this too.

In newer `systemd`-based systems, the [timedatectl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html) command is able to get the hardware clock w/o special permissions:

```
$ timedatectl | head -3
      Local time: Sun 2016-12-18 15:43:08 PST
  Universal time: Sun 2016-12-18 23:43:08 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2016-12-18 23:43:08
```